# How do I create and array and filter the negative numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

The goal here is to loop through all the ".test" containers, create an array. Locate the ".number-container" container, and grab its negative number and put them in an array. so I would then have an array = [1,5,-27,32]. Then the goal was to filter these.

The best I can come up with is just creating an array, I'm having issues trying to get to the next steps.

```
<div class="test"> 
    <h2>main container</h2>
    <p> some sample text</p>
    <div class=".number-container">
    <p> this number is 1</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="test"> 
    <h2>main container</h2>
    <p> some sample text</p>
    <div class=".number-container">
    <p> this number is 5</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="test"> 
    <h2>main container</h2>
    <p> some sample text</p>
    <div class=".number-container">
    <p> this number is -32</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="test"> 
    <h2>main container</h2>
    <p> some sample text</p>
    <div class=".number-container">
    <p> this number is -27</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javacript:

```
$(".test").each(function(i){
      $(".test").text();
      return $(".number-container").filter(function(value) {
        return value < 0;
      });
    });
```

Comment: This statement $(".number-container") will return the p tag "<p> this number is -27</p>" not the number

Comment: Can you change the HTML?  Or are you stuck with that (eg from a 3rd party).  If you can change it, then put the number in a `<span>` (with a class) and just get all of them with a simple `$(".value")`

Comment: I'm trying to figure this out for work. I don't want to show the code and my javascript skills are very very weak at the moment. So I tried to make an example.

Comment: **<div class="test" data-number="-32">** why don't you try to use data attribute :D

Comment: right it will return <p> this number is -27</p> but is there a way to chunk down to just the numbers?

Comment: The example is fine.  I'm asking if you can make it `<div><p>the number is <span class='num'>-27</span></p></div>`

Comment: If you can change the html to either a span or a data- attribute, then it's trivial, if not, then it's a case of parsing the text to extract the number, eg split and take the last value or a regex

Comment: `<div class=".number-container">` is probably meant to be `<div class="number-container">`, right? CSS class names cannot start with, or contain, a `.`.

Comment: Please do not completely change the question by exchanging the code for something completely different. Ask a new question instead.

Comment: I apologize, I grabbed the HTML its actually tables, I can not change the HTML either.

Comment: I can only ask so many questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No jQuery required here. In your question, it remains unclear if you only want the non-negative number, or the negative numbers only. I've added examples for both variants.

```js
const numberContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.test .number-container p');
let arr = [];

for (numberContainer of numberContainers) {
  arr.push(parseInt(numberContainer.textContent.split(' ').pop()));
}

console.log(arr.filter(e=>e>=0));
console.log(arr.filter(e=>e<0));
```

```html
<div class="test"> 
    <h2>main container</h2>
    <p> some sample text</p>
    <div class="number-container">
    <p> this number is 1</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="test"> 
    <h2>main container</h2>
    <p> some sample text</p>
    <div class="number-container">
    <p> this number is 5</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="test"> 
    <h2>main container</h2>
    <p> some sample text</p>
    <div class="number-container">
    <p> this number is -32</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="test"> 
    <h2>main container</h2>
    <p> some sample text</p>
    <div class="number-container">
    <p> this number is -27</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: jQuery offers only disadvantages here. You want Javascript native functions like `split()`, `pop()`, and `filter()` here.

Comment: While a non-jquery solution is of course helpful, please don't try to push your anti-jquery agenda on users that find the jquery syntax much more user friendly and succinct.  jquery/vanilla javascript is a matter of local policy and choice.

Comment: @freedomn-m I disagree in this case as stated in my above comment in which I gave reason why jQuery is not the tool of choice here.

Comment: While not really the place for this discussion, you've not given any reasons other than "offers only disadvantages".  jquery devs always still use native functions such as split/pop/parseInt/filter. The only non-jquery part of your code is the overly verbose `document.querySelectorAll('.test .number-container p')` vs `$(".test .number-container p")` (obv return slightly different results).

Comment: Verbosity is not a relevant disadvantage imo. Aside from nothing preventing you from doing `const $ = document.querySelectorAll` in your code base.

Answer (score 0):

Actually for each iterated element you need to find the `p` containing values, using `.find(".number-container p")`.

Then  you need to get the values inside the `".number-container p"` with `.text()` instead of using only the `value` callback param of `$(".number-container").filter` which will hold a jQuery DOM object.

```
$(".test").each(function(i) {
    let value = $(this).find(".number-container p").text();

    if (value.indexOf("-") == -1) {
      $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

**Note:**

- As the retrieved values are `strings` and not numbers you check for negative values with `value.indexOf("-")`.
- You need to remove the leading `.` from the class names in
  `class=".number-container"`.

**Demo:**

This is a demo that shows only pragraphs with negative values upon button click:

```js
$("#checkForNegativeNumbers").click(function() {
  $(".test").each(function(i) {
    let value = $(this).find(".number-container p").text();

    if (value.indexOf("-") == -1) {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="checkForNegativeNumbers"> check For Negative Numbers</button>
<br />
<div class="test">
  <h2>main container</h2>
  <p> some sample text</p>
  <div class="number-container">
    <p> this number is 1</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="test">
  <h2>main container</h2>
  <p> some sample text</p>
  <div class="number-container">
    <p> this number is 5</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="test">
  <h2>main container</h2>
  <p> some sample text</p>
  <div class="number-container">
    <p> this number is -32</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="test">
  <h2>main container</h2>
  <p> some sample text</p>
  <div class="number-container">
    <p> this number is -27</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As it appears you can't change the HTML, you will need to use `.split()` which assumes the last "word" is always the required value.

Using jquery you can use `.map` to convert a jquery collection to get specific values and process them (in this case check they are `>=0`) and `.toArray()` to convert these to an array.

This assumes the final requirement is an array of numbers.

```js
var nums = $(".number-container p").map(function() { 
    var num = parseInt($(this).text().split(' ').pop());
    return num >= 0 ? num : null;
}).toArray();

console.log(nums);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test"> 
    <h2>main container</h2>
    <p> some sample text</p>
    <div class="number-container">
    <p> this number is 1</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="test"> 
    <h2>main container</h2>
    <p> some sample text</p>
    <div class="number-container">
    <p> this number is 5</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="test"> 
    <h2>main container</h2>
    <p> some sample text</p>
    <div class="number-container">
    <p> this number is -32</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="test"> 
    <h2>main container</h2>
    <p> some sample text</p>
    <div class="number-container">
    <p> this number is -27</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

to do in jQuery way need to change the class name as class="number-container" (remove ".")

```
<div class="test">
    <h2>main container</h2>
    <p> some sample text</p>
    <div class="number-container">
        <p> this number is 1</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="test">
    <h2>main container</h2>
    <p> some sample text</p>
    <div class="number-container">
        <p> this number is 5</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="test">
    <h2>main container</h2>
    <p> some sample text</p>
    <div class="number-container">
        <p> this number is -32</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="test">
    <h2>main container</h2>
    <p> some sample text</p>
    <div class="number-container">
        <p> this number is -27</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and after that you can loop over div element which contains amounts

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        var nonNegativeArray = [];
         $(".number-container").each(function(index,element){
             var p = $(element).children().first();
             var amount = parseInt(p.html().split(' ').pop());
             if (amount > 0){ // will push amount only greater than 0 ( non negative)
                 nonNegativeArray.push(amount);
             }
        });
       console.log(nonNegativeArray); 

    })
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick.

I get all the relevant nodes using `document.querySelectorAll('.number-container')`.

Then i loop through then and gets the `textContent` of each elements. Trimming it removes any unwanted spaces.

I then extract the last non-whitespace collection of characters in the text, runs it through `parseFloat` and pushes it to the list of values.

```js
var values = [];
document.querySelectorAll('.number-container').forEach(function(value) {
  var txt = value.textContent.trim();
  values.push(parseFloat(txt.substr(txt.search(/\S+$/igm))));
});
console.log(values);
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <h2>main container</h2>
  <p> some sample text</p>
  <div class="number-container">
    <p> this number is 1</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="test">
  <h2>main container</h2>
  <p> some sample text</p>
  <div class="number-container">
    <p> this number is 5</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="test">
  <h2>main container</h2>
  <p> some sample text</p>
  <div class="number-container">
    <p> this number is -32</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="test">
  <h2>main container</h2>
  <p> some sample text</p>
  <div class="number-container">
    <p> this number is -27</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why?  While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.